# Magento 2.3.2: Product stock status is not automatically updated to Out of Stock on order placed

Tags: magento, magento2, inventory

I have facing issue in admin product stock status Out of Stock once order placed in Magento 2.3.2

When a customer orders an item (and I only have 1 in stock) it would be reserved for them and this item should automatically be shown as out of stock or order as a back order.

But what is happening is that this 1 item in stock won't be removed from website or shown as back order until I mark the first order as shipped.

This is allowing other customer to make a purchase, when there is only 1 and has been sold

Here is screenshot of my settings in admin catalog => inventory :
 [image]

I see that 'yes' is selected for decrease stock when order is placed but this isn't being applied.

It is only being applied once order is marked as shipped

During this time, other customers can purchase the same product too.

Answer (score 1):

In latest magento version 2.3, the new feature saleable qty has been released.

You can check saleable qty field in products grid.

So this will be decreased after placing an order and the default qty will be decreased afte the shipment.

Can you please check whether are you able to place an order if saleable qty is zero.

Comment: yes, my saleable qty is 0 still i am able to place order